# Tomcat 9 Http/2 "Error reading request, ignored"

Tags: tomcat, http2, tomcat9, apache-httpclient-5.x

I m using tomcat 9.0.5(jdk-9.0.4+11) to serve my requests which also have Http/2 enabled for persistent connection and my client also uses the same version of java, I need to open a persistent connection to the server from client and reuse indefinitely. I can successfully connect to my server from client and send request(Post with requestBody) but after 3 requests(exactly 3) the server throws as exception as follows,

> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error
>   reading request, ignored  java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http2.HpackDecoder.handleIndex(HpackDecoder.java:270)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http2.HpackDecoder.decode(HpackDecoder.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Parser.readHeaderPayload(Http2Parser.java:418)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Parser.readHeadersFrame(Http2Parser.java:252)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Parser.readFrame(Http2Parser.java:97)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Parser.readFrame(Http2Parser.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

So a connection is open for only three request after which server closes the connection upon this exception.

p.s: I m using httpclient-5(beta) for establishing persistent connection from my client.
If the queryParam/requestBody is static content the connection is kept persistent. but, if the queryParam/requestBody have some dynamic content(like timestamps) the connection is closed with the above error I don't know the relation between the data in the post body and the tcp connection

I can't post my request body as it is against policy I will post after masking all my request params, my request will look something like this,

```
String postBody = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" + 
                "<XX xxx=\"1000000005011\" xxx=\"true\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"0\" xxx=\"P|TA|D|J|M\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"1\" xxx=\"true\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"xxx\" xxx=\"8265\"  xxx=\"true\" avgDnsTime=\"null\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"EVAL_USER\" xxx=\"1000000000011\" xxx=\"2\" xxx=\"true\" xxx=\"http://localhost:8080/app/xxx\" xxx=\"true\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"av_xxx\" ut=\"1528453675150\" xxx=\"URL\" xxx=\"70\" time=\""+(System.currentTimeMillis()+"")+"\" xxx=\"1440\" xxx=\"48\" xxx=\"1\" xxx=\"1\" postUrl=\"xxx.com:8443\">\n" + 
                "<XXX xxx=\"\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"1000000005011\" xxx=\"60\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"127.0.0.1\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"default\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"false\" xxx=\"http://www.example.com\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"false\" m=\"G\" xxx=\"0\" xxx=\"\" xxx=\"\" t=\"30\" xxx=\"English\"><XD></XD><XH xxx=\"\" xxx=\"_sep_\" xxx=\"\"/><XI xxx=\"\" xxx=\"\"/>\n" + 
                "</XXX>\n" + 
                "</XX>";
```

If anyone have any idea about this exception kindly help

TIA

Comment: Hpack error suggests a problem with a header you are sending. HTTP/2 is much more strict about these so spaces in header names, extra colons... etc. can all cause problems in HTTP/2 even though you got away with them in HTTP/1. Can you list your headers for your 3rd Request (maybe by reverting back to HTTP/1 temporarily)?

Comment: I am not sending any headers, may be the default headers??? Still why it fails after three requests exactly??? Also notice it fails if parameters or request body have any content like time stamp, otherwise it’s okay with static content...

Comment: Because your dynamic content is returning some bad headers but your static content is not? And you only ask for dynamic content on the third request? That’s my best guess. Does it work fine under HTTP/1?

Comment: No I send dynamic content in all the request, the time stamp keeps changing for every request. Yes it was working under http1.1 and now upgrading it to http/2

Comment: You say “if the queryParam/requestBody is static content” it works. You also say you “send dynamic content in all the request”?!? I’ve given my best guess with the limited information I have. Something is clearly different between the working and non-working requests. You need to show these two different requests if you want anyone to be able to help you any more.

Comment: I could not post it in comments as its too long so I have updated the answer, look for the parameter called "time". if its configured as "System.currentmillis()" it fails after 3 request or If I configure it as static value like "1529485036702" it works as expected.

Comment: You really are making this as difficult as possible to try to help you so I’m going to bow out now as don’t think I can help you any further. Best I can suggest is that this piece: `+””)+` looks suspect. Why are you adding a blank string? Is that to convert it to string? Either way the error message alludes to HPACK which is to do with the request or response *header* not the *body* as you’ve given. Though it is telling that when you hard core that value it works so maybe that error message is not correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BarryPollard for taking time to reply my question, I will try your suggestions and see it will help anyway.

Comment: @BarryPollard it seems the queryParam we send have some encoding problem, instead I send the data in the request payload and there are no problem, your suggestion helped me to fix this.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments

HPACK is the HTTP Header Compression algorithm used in HTTP/2. So the error messages suggest a problem with your HTTP headers.

HTTP/1 was very forgiving with malformed HTTP headers, but HTTP/2 is much more strict. Extra newlines, open quotes, extra colons...etc. can all cause problems.

Additionally, under HTTP/2 all the request methods and params are consider HTTP Headers.

So, this in HTTP/1:

```
GET /page.html HTTP/1.1
Header1: Header1Value
Header2: Header2Value
```

becomes this in HTTP/2:

```
:method: GET
:path: /page.html
Header1: Header1Value
Header2: Header2Value
```

So check all your headers (including your path) for malformed requests.

In your case it was a badly encoded query Param in our :path: header.

Comment: Ya as I said in the comments your suggestion guides me in right way to debug and fix the problem, thanks :)